# Class App\Http\Controllers\MyController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

controller.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, AuthorizesResources, DispatchesJobs,    ValidatesRequests;
}
class MyController extends Controller
{
    function getIndex()
    {
        $hello="Hello world!!";
        return view('mainpage',['hello'=>$hello]);
    }

}
```

route.php

```
Route::resource('/', 'MyController');
```

на выходе получаю следующую ошибку при создании своего контроллера

> Class App\Http\Controllers\MyController does not exist

Comment: И для чего вы определяете `App\Http\Controller\Controller`? Ну и класс `MyController` не будет обнаружен стандартным автозагрузчиком

Comment: @DmitriySimushev где вы видите подобную строку?

Comment: Namespace + имя класса -> получается то имя, что я привел... вы бы разобрались, для начала, с логикой именования классов в PHP

Comment: очень важное примечание что аж.....

Comment: Тем не менее, ответ на ваш вопрос я уже дал: "_класс `MyController` не будет обнаружен стандартным автозагрузчиком_".

Comment: в документации по этому поводу нигде не сказано.ну или покажите ссылку, если несложно

Comment: Почитайте про [PSR4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). Развернутый ответ мне писать лень, возможно кто-то другой придет и сделает это доброе дело =)

Comment: Я вам уже сказал: "проблема в автозагрузчике файлов". Так что название **файла/класса** "не ок".

Comment: если у вас класс называется MyController, то оно должно находится в файле таким же названием , то есть MyController.php

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::resource('/', 'MyController@getindex()');
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Автолоадер подгружает файлы по названию класса, а вы пытаетесь засунуть 2 класса в 1 файл.
Вы должны создать новый контроллер в `App\Http\Controllers\`, а не дописывать к базовому контроллеру ларавел.  У вас получиться вот такой код:

`MyController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    function getIndex()
    {
        $hello="Hello world!!";
        return view('mainpage',['hello'=>$hello]);
    }

}
```

P.S. только заметил, что вопрос был задан в 16м году:)